# GEE trend analysis using MODIS LST

Tags: google-earth-engine

The code was processed successfully but the result was like this, I don't know what went wrong. Can you correct it for me?

[image]

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1');
var createTimeBand = function (image){
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start')
  .divide(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
};
var data = modis.select('LST_Day_1km')
                          .filterDate('2019-09-28','2020-01-05')
                          .map(createTimeBand);
Map.addLayer(trend.clip(table),{min:0, max:[-100,100,10000], bands:['scale','scale','offset']},'fit');
```

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete, `trend` is not defined.

Comment: I refer to this code, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNE7ZCd6ob0&t=323s

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce your problem from code in a YouTube video. Include the variables you imported in the question. To make things even easier for people that want to help you, include a link to the code (using the `Get Link` button in the Code editor).

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6ff0e5be85193b6f0333efedd4c7b5b6

Answer (score 1):

Your visParams min/max are probably a bit off. (You didn't share your `table` asset, so I'm using the map bounds as region.)

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start')
    .divide(1000 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365))
}
var data = modis.select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterDate('2019-09-28', '2019-11-30')
  .map(createTimeBand)
  .map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .set('system:time-start', img.get('system:time-start'))
})

var trend = data.select(['system:time_start', 'LST_Day_1km'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit())
  
var visParams = {
  bands: ['scale', 'scale', 'offset'],
  min: [-2e5, -2e5, -6e7],
  max: [-1e4, -1e4, 3e7]
}
Map.addLayer(trend.clip(table), visParams, 'fit')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/30c1d3ea38023b1f755900adc50dccc2